# Updating array of dicts position field

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have the following code for updating a position value in an array of dictionaries. 
When I update the position of one object I want to change the position of the others depending on their value.

```
items = [{'position': 0, '_id': 'Bob'}, {'position': 1, '_id': 'Tom'}, {'position': 2, u'_id': 'Sam'}]
data = {'_id': 'Tom', 'position': 2}

updated_items = []
for item in items:
    if item["_id"] == data["_id"]:
        item["position"] = data["position"]
        updated_items.append(item)
    elif item["position"] < data["position"]:
        updated_items.append(item)
    else:
        item["position"] += 1
        updated_items.append(item)
```

The output of this code is:

```
updated_items = [{'position': 0, '_id': 'Bob'}, {'position': 2, '_id': 'Tom'}, {'position': 3, u'_id': 'Sam'}]
```

This is expected and correct. However, if the object I want to update is in position 0 then the output is as follows:

```
items = [{'position': 0, '_id': 'Bob'}, {'position': 1, '_id': 'Tom'}, {'position': 2, u'_id': 'Sam'}]
data = {'_id': 'Bob', 'position': 2}

updated_items = [{'position': 2, '_id': 'Bob'}, {'position': 1, '_id': 'Tom'}, {'position': 3, u'_id': 'Sam'}]
```

How would I solve this problem and do it in a more efficient way.

Comment: Is the key `'position'` just a coincidence in naming, or is your `updated_items` list supposed to be sorted based on `'position'`?

Comment: The array is not required to be sorted by the 'position' field. I just need the 'position' of the other dictionaries to be set depending on a positional update of an object already in the array.

Comment: So what are you expecting instead of second example?

Comment: `updated_items = [{'position': 0, '_id': 'Tom'}, {'position': 1, '_id': 'Sam'}, {'position': 2, u'_id': 'Bob'}]` I would like Tom and Sam to slide down into positions 0 and 1.

Comment: I see this hasn't had any response for a while. I decided to look at the logic and was curious. The OP says the output of the first example is correct. Although I would expect (based on the description and shifting) that the output for the first test case should look like: `[{'position': 0, '_id': 'Bob'}, {'position': 2, '_id': 'Tom'}, {'position': 1, u'_id': 'Sam'}]` (the order doesn't matter but I would expect that they'd be number  0, 1 & 2. Not 0, 2 & 3. Am I missing something or did I misinterpret the question? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did ask a followup comment to remove some ambiguity in what type of output was acceptable. I think the question leaves some things open for interpretation. The code below is designed to work on unsorted lists. It will renumber elements between the range of the dictitem position we want to update and the position we change to. This code will shift in the appropriate direction (this is because we can be changing to a position smaller than we were or larger than we were).

```
# Update the dictionary list entry matching the id in dictitem with a new position
def updatedictlist(dictlist, dictitem):

    # Get the dict item from the dict list matching the id in dictitem
    upditem = next(item for (index, item) in enumerate(dictlist) if item['_id'] == dictitem['_id'])

    # If there is a StopIteration exception then the dictitem position we 
    # are trying to update TO doesn't exist so we can go ahead and update
    # the dictitem with a new position without making any other changes.
    try:
        dstitem = next(item for (index, item) in enumerate(dictlist) \
                            if item['position'] == dictitem['position'])
    except StopIteration:
        # Update the dictlist and return the list.
        upditem['position'] = dictitem['position']
        return dictlist

    # We only want to update the values between range of values we care about
    # leaving the rest alone.
    rangelow, rangehigh = (min(upditem['position'], dstitem['position']), \
                           max(upditem['position'], dstitem['position']))

    # Since we are replacing a value it matters whether the destination is
    # ahead of us or behind us.
    direction = -1 if upditem['position'] - dstitem['position'] < 0 else 1

    # Shift the values that fall within the position range we are processing
    for item in dictlist:
        if (rangelow <= item['position'] <= rangehigh):
            item['position'] += direction

    # Finally process the dictitem we wanted to update
    upditem['position'] = dictitem['position']

    return dictlist

items = [{'position': 0, '_id': 'Bob'}, {'position': 1, '_id': 'Tom'}, {'position': 2, u'_id': 'Sam'}]
data = {'_id': 'Tom', 'position': 2}
print updatedictlist(copy.deepcopy(items), data)

data = {'_id': 'Bob', 'position': 2}
print updatedictlist(copy.deepcopy(items), data)
```

The output is:

```
[{'position': 0, '_id': 'Bob'}, {'position': 2, '_id': 'Tom'}, {'position': 1, u'_id': 'Sam'}]
[{'position': 2, '_id': 'Bob'}, {'position': 0, '_id': 'Tom'}, {'position': 1, u'_id': 'Sam'}]
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks very much for you answer. It's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for not constructing my question better. Excellent work.